# How to fix "ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I wanna make a model with multiple inputs. So, I try to build a model like this.

```
# define two sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=(32,64,1))
inputB = Input(shape=(32,1024))
 
# CNN
x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu')(inputA)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(500, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(500, activation='relu')(x)
x = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)
 
# DNN
y = layers.Flatten()(inputB)
y = Dense(64, activation="relu")(y)
y = Dense(250, activation="relu")(y)
y = Dense(500, activation="relu")(y)
y = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)
 
# Combine the output of the two models
combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])
 

# combined outputs
z = Dense(300, activation="relu")(combined)
z = Dense(100, activation="relu")(combined)
z = Dense(1, activation="softmax")(combined)

model = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)

model.summary()

opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt,
    metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

and the summary
:
_

But, when i try to train this model,

```
history = model.fit([trainimage, train_product_embd],train_label,
    validation_data=([validimage,valid_product_embd],valid_label), epochs=10, 
    steps_per_epoch=100, validation_steps=10)
```

the problem happens....
:

```
 ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-18-2b79f16d63c0> in <module>()
 ----> 1 history = model.fit([trainimage, train_product_embd],train_label,
 validation_data=([validimage,valid_product_embd],valid_label),
 epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=100, validation_steps=10)

 4 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
 in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)    1470         ret =
 tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,    1471      
 self._handle, args,
 -> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)    1473         if run_metadata:    1474          
 proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
 
 ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Resource
 exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[800000,32,30,62] and
 type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by
 allocator GPU_0_bfc     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]] Hint: If you
 want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add
 report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
 allocation info.
 
     [[metrics/acc/Mean_1/_185]] Hint: If you want to see a list of
 allocated tensors when OOM happens, add
 report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
 allocation info.
 
   (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with
 shape[800000,32,30,62] and type float on
 /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc    
 [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]] Hint: If you want to see a list of
 allocated tensors when OOM happens, add
 report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
 allocation info.
 
 0 successful operations. 0 derived errors ignored.
```

Thanks for reading and hopefully helping me :)

Comment: I was using batch size = 1024. After changing to 768 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

*OOM* stands for "out of memory". Your GPU is running out of memory, so it can't allocate memory for this tensor. There are a few things you can do:

- Decrease the number of filters in your `Dense`, `Conv2D` layers
- Use a smaller `batch_size` (or increase `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`)
- Use grayscale images (you can use [`tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale))
- Reduce the number of layers
- Use `MaxPooling2D` layers after convolutional layers
- Reduce the size of your images (you can use [`tf.image.resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize) for that)
- Use smaller `float` precision for your input, namely `np.float32`
- If you're using a pre-trained model, freeze the first layers (like [this](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-layers-and-do-finetuning))

There is more useful information about this error:

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[800000,32,30,62]
```

This is a weird shape. If you're working with images, you should normally have 3 or 1 channel. On top of that, it seems like you are passing your entire dataset at once; you should instead pass it in batches.

Comment: its a bit weird that im getting same error (after switching cpu for gpu version) just by doing sequential and adding the layers, not even a fit or anything. shape[173056,4096] and type float. is it normal to get allocation errors when you arent even passing batches?

Comment: Yes, because a neural network is just a huge matrix of float values, just like input batches.

Answer (score 2):

From `[800000,32,30,62]` it seems your model put all the data in one batch.

Try specified batch size like

```
history = model.fit([trainimage, train_product_embd],train_label, validation_data=([validimage,valid_product_embd],valid_label), epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=100, validation_steps=10, batch_size=32)
```

If it still OOM then try reduce the `batch_size`

Comment: OP specificed `steps_per_epoch=100` so I don't think that's the case. `batch_size` should be automatically set to `sample_size/steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: I tried 'batch_size' first. But, there was an error :"ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data)." Thank you for your opinion by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well.

You can try reducing trainable parameters by using some form of Transfer Learning - try freezing the initial few layers and use lower batch sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common reason for this case to arise would be the absence of MaxPooling layers.
Use the same architecture, but add atleast one MaxPool layer after Conv2D layers. This might even improve the overall performance of the model.
You can even try reducing the depth of the model, i.e., remove the unnecessary layers and optimize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions :

- Reduce your Dimension because of the limited RAM on GPU. like, Nvidia
  GTX 1060 3gb
- Reduce your Batchsize of datagen.flow (by default set 32
  so you have to set 8/16/24

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a stale process was using most of the RAM available on the GPU.

**Simple solution:** (for Nvidia GPUs)

- Type `nvidia-smi` on the terminal and note the PID of the process(es) with large memory usage
- Tpye `sudo kill PID`, with the PID from above