# Cannot solve ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm Having trouble solving this error:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 1050, 1300, 1]`

I am trying to create a face generator based on image.jpgs i give
all works well till I Create **GAN(Generative adversarial network)**
Note: i have set all(687) my images to be of the dimensions of `520x420`
and all my images are color images,

Here is my code if it helps:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, LeakyReLU, \
    Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

images = []
dim1 = []
dim2 = []
images_path = 'images'
# no_of_images=len(images_path)
for image_name, num in zip(os.listdir(images_path), range(687)):
    full_path = os.path.join(images_path, image_name)
    image = imread(os.path.join(images_path, image_name))
    images.append(image)

# Number of images
# print(len(os.listdir(images_path)))


# Converting list into array
images = np.asarray(images)
# print(images.shape) = (687, 420, 520, 3)

images = images / 255

# setting minimum value of image array to -1 and max to +1
images = images.reshape(-1, 420, 520, 3) * 2 - 1
print(images.shape)

# Setting random seed
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# number of neurons in the smallest layer
coding_size = 200

# Creating Generator
generator = Sequential()
generator.add(Dense(int(420 / 4) * int(520 / 4) * 86, input_shape=[coding_size]))
generator.add(Reshape([int(420 / 4), int(520 / 4), 86]))
generator.add(BatchNormalization())
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=5, strides=5, padding='same',
                              activation='relu'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization())
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same',
                              activation='tanh'))
generator.summary()

# Creating discriminator
discriminator = Sequential()
discriminator.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same',
                         activation=LeakyReLU(0.3), input_shape=(420, 520, 3)))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.5))
discriminator.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation=LeakyReLU(0.3)))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.5))
discriminator.add(Flatten())
discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Creating Generative Adversarial Network
GAN = Sequential([generator, discriminator])
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
discriminator.trainable = False

GAN.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# setting up batch_size
batch_size = 32  # training time is inversely proportional to batch_size

# my_data = x_train (for all numbers)
my_data = images
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data).shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
# for really large dataset use buffer-size

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)
# drop_remainder = True because 687/64 = 10.73 is not an integer, so we remover the other images
# we have 10 batches
epochs = 20

# creating training loops
generator, discriminator = GAN.layers

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f"currently on epoch {epoch + 1}")
    i = 0
    for x_batch in dataset:
        i += 1
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(f"\tcurrently on batch number:{i} of {len(my_data) // batch_size}")

        # discriminator training phase
        noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, coding_size])
        gen_images = generator(noise)

        # concatonating generated images with real images

        x_fake_vs_real = tf.concat([gen_images, tf.dtypes.cast(x_batch, tf.float32)], axis=0)

        # setting target label
        y1 = tf.constant([[0.0]] * batch_size + [[1.0]] * batch_size)
        # 0 => fake generated images
        # 1 => real images

        # we want the discriminator now (after compiling GAN)
        discriminator.trainable = True
        discriminator.train_on_batch(x_fake_vs_real, y1)

        # training the generator (Phase:2)
        noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, coding_size])
        y2 = tf.constant([[1.0]] * batch_size)
        # to avoid error
        discriminator.trainable = False
        GAN.train_on_batch(noise, y2)
print("TRAINING COMPLETE!")
# let us see whether generator can produce images like real images

# 10 fake images
noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[10, coding_size])

images_noise = generator(noise)
# images.shape = TensorShape([10,28,28])

for image in images_noise:
    plt.imshow(image.numpy().reshape(420, 520))
    plt.show()
```

The output:

```
C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:/Users/astro/Pythonprojects/generating_face/rough.py
2020-07-14 17:34:44.467116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
(687, 420, 520, 3)
2020-07-14 17:35:16.908283: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.057551: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.515GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-07-14 17:35:17.058332: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.099460: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.128073: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.135191: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.174991: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.190853: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.292639: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.293344: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-07-14 17:35:17.296905: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-14 17:35:17.354537: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1c93c31e7b0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-14 17:35:17.354746: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-07-14 17:35:17.356677: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.515GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-07-14 17:35:17.357213: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.357362: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.357506: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.357881: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.359120: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.359266: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.359694: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-07-14 17:35:17.359922: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-07-14 17:35:20.123836: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-07-14 17:35:20.124040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-07-14 17:35:20.124157: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2020-07-14 17:35:20.138550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2917 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-07-14 17:35:20.144365: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1c94356c150 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-14 17:35:20.159393: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1650, Compute Capability 7.5
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 1173900)           235953900 
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 105, 130, 86)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 105, 130, 86)      344       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 525, 650, 64)      137664    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 525, 650, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 1050, 1300, 1)     1601      
=================================================================
```

I think i need this last layer to be (None, 420, 520, 3), but i don't know how.

```
Total params: 236,093,765
Trainable params: 236,093,465
Non-trainable params: 300
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/astro/Pythonprojects/generating_face/rough.py", line 73, in <module>
    GAN = Sequential([generator, discriminator])
  File "C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 213, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 885, in __call__
    input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
  File "C:\Users\astro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 212, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 1050, 1300, 1]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this line, which should be 3 and not 1:

```
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same',
                              activation='tanh'))
```

I'm not sure your shapes will match after that, though, because the discriminator expects `input_shape=(420, 520, 3)` but the full shape you're passing is `[None, 1050, 1300, 1]`. But I think it will be one step closer.

Comment: Using what you suggested gives me Conv2DTr (None, 1050, 1300, 3) which is close, but i cannot think of a way to change 1050 to 420 and 1300 to 520.

Comment: use `kernel_size=3` and `strides=2` for both layers in the generator

Comment: Thanks a lot! the problem was solved, but gives me another error, tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,40,210,260] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
 Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_1420]

Comment: You're running out of memory but that's not something I can help you with, unfortunately.

Comment: I guess I have to figure something out. Thanks a lot anyways. Stay safe!

Comment: Update: Solved the out of memory issue by reducing the batch size to 16. The program now outputs the generated images.

Comment: Oh I should have told you one of my most upvoted [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394947/how-to-fix-resourceexhaustederror-oom-when-allocating-tensor/59395251#59395251) suggests ways to do that. Sorry I forgot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 687 number of training images, each with 520x420 pixels and if all are colored images i.e.(rgb) you can directly put

```
images=images.reshape(687,520,420,3)
```

where 3 stands for 3 channels i.e.(rgb)
whereas if the images are grayscale instead of 3 you should write 1

```
input_shape=(520,420,3)
```