# ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,64,224,224]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, gpu

Got ResourceExhaustedError while training deep learning algorithm on NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU using tensorflow with memory_limit: 1721342363

I am training 2870 images and its working well using CPU but on GPU it seems to be getting restricted due to memory limit. Have I turned on a limit of memory on my GPU or do I have no option but to use my CPU?
It took me 70 mins on my CPU and that is why I chose to run on my GPU.
But while training

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
history = model.fit(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=20, batch_size=32)
```

Got this error:

```
Epoch 1/20
 1/45 [..............................] - ETA: 9:46 - loss: 1.8638 - accuracy: 0.1667
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 3
      1 #Compile the model 
      2 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
----> 3 history = model.fit(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=20, batch_size=32)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:1184, in Model.fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1177 with tf.profiler.experimental.Trace(
   1178     'train',
   1179     epoch_num=epoch,
   1180     step_num=step,
   1181     batch_size=batch_size,
   1182     _r=1):
   1183   callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184   tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185   if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186     context.async_wait()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:885, in Function.__call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    882 compiler = "xla" if self._jit_compile else "nonXla"
    884 with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885   result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    887 new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    888 without_tracing = (tracing_count == new_tracing_count)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:917, in Function._call(self, *args, **kwds)
    914   self._lock.release()
    915   # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    916   # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 917   return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    918 elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    919   # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
    920   # in parallel.
    921   self._lock.release()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py:3039, in Function.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3036 with self._lock:
   3037   (graph_function,
   3038    filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 3039 return graph_function._call_flat(
   3040     filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py:1963, in ConcreteFunction._call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1959 possible_gradient_type = gradients_util.PossibleTapeGradientTypes(args)
   1960 if (possible_gradient_type == gradients_util.POSSIBLE_GRADIENT_TYPES_NONE
   1961     and executing_eagerly):
   1962   # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1963   return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1964       ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1965 forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1966     args,
   1967     possible_gradient_type,
   1968     executing_eagerly)
   1969 forward_function, args_with_tangents = forward_backward.forward()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py:591, in _EagerDefinedFunction.call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    589 with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    590   if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 591     outputs = execute.execute(
    592         str(self.signature.name),
    593         num_outputs=self._num_outputs,
    594         inputs=args,
    595         attrs=attrs,
    596         ctx=ctx)
    597   else:
    598     outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(
    599         str(self.signature.name),
    600         num_outputs=self._num_outputs,
   (...)
    603         ctx=ctx,
    604         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:59, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57 try:
     58   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62   if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,64,224,224] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node model/block1_conv2/Relu (defined at \AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11956\3538519329.py:3) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_1205]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394947/how-to-fix-resourceexhaustederror-oom-when-allocating-tensor)

Answer (score 0):

I might be not entirely right on the details, but the training process looks like this from the GPU memory perspective:

1. the network is loaded into the GPU memory
2. a batch is loaded into the GPU memory
3. trainable parameters are computed on the GPU

So there are several ways to reduce GPU memory usage:

1. Reduce the number of trainable parameters so each training step requires less computations. You can do this by either reducing the size of the net or by making some of the later layers non-trainable if the net is pretrained ([tf.keras.applications](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications) has a lot of networks pretrained on the imagenet).
   To make layers of the [Functional](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) net (in which the abovementioned nets are written) untrainable, you should switch their .trainable attribute to False:

Say to freeze all the layers starting from the 100th one you need to:

```
ind_to_freeze = 100
for layer in net.layers[:100]:
    layer.trainable=False
```

2. Reduce the image shapes so each batch requires less memory. Generally, this will lower the accuracy.
3. Reduce the batch size so each batch requires less memory.

Also I see you've loaded all 2870 images into the (CPU) memory at once. I recommend using generator instead that takes filenames and reads instead. You can read about building native tf.data.Datasets [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)